# Angular 10 - Openlayers get map coordinates on (click)

Tags: javascript, angular, dictionary, gis, openlayers

I have an OpenLayers map in my Angular map component. I need to get the click coordinate of the map on the Angular `(click)` event. In Javascript is easy, just adding the following code:

```
map.on('click', function(evt) {
  var coordinate = evt.coordinate;
}
```

In Angular on the `map.component.html`, I added the following code:

```
<div id="map" (click)="getCoord($event)" class="map"></div>
```

And created the `getCoord()` function in my `map.component.ts` just like this:

```
getCoord(event: any){
    var coordinate = this.map.getEventPixel(event);
 }
```

For the same click event, javascript returns this coordinate, which is the one I need

> Array [ -180047.42012573266, 5279667.9723422285 ]

But in angular, I get this one:

> Array [ 480, 221 ]

Any idea of how can I get the correct coordinate using Angular, or how can I convert the second into the first one? I'm really stuck in this.

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you add the click handler on your component side, on the actual map instance (and not the dom element)?

Comment: @David Thanks, but I can't find the way for doing that. Does Angular have a click handler on the component side?

Comment: How you do instantiate your map? After instantiating it, you can get an instance of the ol map. Then just use map.on... on that instance

Comment: `var coordinate = this.map.getEventCoordinate(event);`

Comment: Thanks @mike , it worked perfectly

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally solved with `getEventCoordinate()`:

```
 getCoord(event: any){
    var coordinate = this.map.getEventCoordinate(event);
 }
```

for the click event generated in the `map.component.html`:

```
<div id="map" (click)="getCoord($event)" class="map"></div>
```